# Combobox Autofill and select Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox

I have a combobox with 2 columns (ICD10.[Code], ICD10.[Text]). I want to be able to search-suggest from both columns, and if I search after Kolera, I want to be able to select it, and then it will put in the ID code, not the name.

How do I do this? or what should I start searching for? I don't even know what I'm supposed to search for to solve this problem.

Heres a picture of my combobox
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvFTk.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to search after the ICD10 code and the name, you will need two combo boxes. The first is the one you already have which enables you to search for the code. For the second, you should make a copy of the first, then sort your data source by the ICD10 name column (is not absolutely necessary but makes sense when viewing the dropdown list) and changing the width of your first column (the ICD10 code) to 0 in order to prevent the list from showing your first column.

Both combo boxes will still contain the ICD10 code, but the second one will allow you to select the code by the name column.